# Second derivative of the Associated Legendre functions

Tags: special-functions, numerics

I would like to compute, as part of the solution of the Laplace equation using the Fast Multipole Method, the second derivative of [the associated legendre functions of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLegendrePolynomial.html) .
Specifically, I am looking for C implementations or just the correct recurrence relation to use to write the function myself.

I have tried to look for recurrence relations and found [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1464189500001010) but I suspect that it might not be correct.

I have also tried to search for ready-to-use functions like [these](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Associated-Legendre-Polynomials-and-Spherical-Harmonics.html) but I have only stumbled upon functions for the first derivative of the associated functions, not the second.

If somebody can point me in the right direction, I will be really grateful!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you looking for the derivative with respect to the order, degree or variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the recurrence relations for the first derivative (with respect to the variable) in the Digital Library of Mathematical Functions ([DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov)) in [Chapter 14](http://dlmf.nist.gov/14), sections [14.10](http://dlmf.nist.gov/14.10) and [14.11](http://dlmf.nist.gov/14.11). You'll have to take care of the stability of the recurrence, though. You should consult the references mentioned in this chapter (see final section on [software](http://dlmf.nist.gov/14.34) and the references it points to).

I think that the GSL library you mention does compute higher order derivatives (with respect to the variable). You can find another implementation in [SciPy](http://scipy.org) where it is explicitly mentioned that the routine calculates higher order derivatives (see [man page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.lpmn.html#scipy.special.lpmn)).